# indexing data frame using function parameters

Tags: r, function, parameters

Taking the following data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(n=rep(LETTERS[1:4],times=5),
               x=rnorm(20,4,1))
```

How can I reproduce this slice

```
df[df$n %in% c("A","C"),]
```

using a function call like

```
dffilter(df,n,c("A","C"))
```

Wrong function-code:

```
dffilter<-function(df,cl,fltr) {
  df[df$cl %in% fltr,]
}
```

What is the right function-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dffilter<-function(df,col,fltr) {
res = df[df[,col] %in% fltr,]
return(res)
}

dffilter(df, "n", c("A","C"))
```